# Where are the PHP directories on Mac OS X?

Tags: php, mac-osx

I'm trying to configure PHP on Mac OS X (10.5.7) and am really confused as to where this program "lives".

Here's what I've found / not found:

php: `/usr/bin/php`
php.ini:  `/etc/php.ini`
extensions directory: `/usr/lib/php/extensions`

Are there other places where PHP components are located?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
locate php
```

[Here](http://developer.apple.com/mac/articles/internet/phpeasyway.html) is an article that may provide some guidance.

Another article: [Working with PHP 5 in Mac OS X 10.5](http://www.procata.com/blog/archives/2007/10/28/working-with-php-5-in-mac-os-x-105/)

One from php.org: [Using the bundled PHP](http://www.php.net/manual/en/install.macosx.bundled.php)

Comment: that's somewhat helpful... finds anything with "php" in the filename, thanks (although i would rather hear where it's supposed to be located)

Comment: hmm, good enough, i guess!